Mail merge in Microsoft Word finishes successfully, but no email was sent out?
I am trying to send several emails via mail merge and I am using Microsoft Word and Outlook.
I set up my mail account in Outlook, and I can send and receive emails without any problems.
Now, I am using Microsoft Word for mail merge, but I am not able to send any emails. The Microsoft Word mail merge finishes successfully, but no email is sent out.
As Microsoft Word is not an email client, how does it send emails to recipients? Does it use Outlook?
How can I check the connection between Microsoft Word and Outlook to ensure that it uses the correct version of Outlook and not a different email client that is not set up properly?
Do you have any other ideas on how I can debug this situation?
Update 1: I followed these instructions and still it doesn't send the emails.

Is Outlook set as your default email program on your computer? Which OS? What versions of Word and Outlook? Have you done any research on this? When you say the process finished, did you click Send Mail Messages in Word? Have you reviewed this document: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mail-merge-to-send-bulk-email-messages-0f123521-20ce-4aa8-8b62-ac211dedefa4 Please EDIT your post to improve and clarify it.

Is there any updates?
